# linux running command as root from c code that run as normal user

Tags: c++, linux

I have a c++ code and I need to running from it a command to adjust the system time.
so I thought using system("su root -c date hh:mm") command from my c++ code.
The problem is that when I write 'su root -c date hh:mm' in the terminal its requires password after, and how can I pass the password to the system command in one line?
or another solution...
Thanks!

Comment: Besides the big security hole that would exist if the password could be "passed" like that, what about systems where the `root` user doesn't have a password?

Comment: You'd better explain why your unprivileged program needs to do this action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround is to modify the `sudoers` file and remove the requirement of a password from your user ID for a particular script to have sudo privileges.

Enter `sudo visudo`

After this, add the details in the following manner.

`username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/script`

Another method would be to pipe the password as input to the sudo command. I don't recommend this, as you would be entering your password as plain text. You could use a variable to store the password, and then access it, but it still isn't a secure method. You could run the command as

```
echo $PASSWORD | sudo ./a.out
```

Comment: This is a good advice but the problem 'sudo visudo' doesn't work on my linux distribution, I have tried with few combinations, 'root su - visudo' and some more but.. nothing.

Comment: @Ron , what about the second method suggested?

Comment: the second method (with the echo) is fine and good. the first one was better but the problem I can't grant the privileges  on that linux.
Thanks!!